# PyQt to exe. No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore'

Tags: python, pyqt, py2exe

I am trying to compile PyQt py to exe using py2exe.
    import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

```
#PythonApplication1.py
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Hello world")
    window.setCentralWidget(button)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

-

```
#setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(windows=[{"script":"PythonApplication1.py"}], options={"py2exe":{"includes":["sip"]}})
```

$python setup.py py2exe --includes sip

When I run exe there is only error window: See the logfile 'C:\dist\PythonApplication1.log' for details.

```
#PythonApplication1.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonApplication1.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<loader>", line 10, in <module>
  File "<loader>", line 8, in __load
ImportError: (No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore') 'C:\\dist\\PyQt5.QtWidgets.pyd'
```

Comment: You could try adding `import PyQt5.QtCore` to your *PythonApplication1.py*.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to build an executable application by modifying *setup.py*

```
setup(windows=[{"script": "PythonApplication1.py"}],
      options= {"py2exe": {"includes": ["sip", "PyQt5.QtCore", "PyQt5.QtGui"]}})
```

and by copying *qwindows.dll* to *dist/platforms/* directory.

An alternative method is to add import statements

```
import PyQt5.QtCore
import PyQt5.QtGui
```

to the main program.

Comment: This does not help for me. But your comment for my question does.

Comment: @Ufx odd, I tested both methods and both seemed to work except for that *qwindows.dll*